# errors on trying to import database to local site via ssh

Tags: database, shell, ssh, import

I am new to ssh and am trying to import a database into a local site I've set up with MAMP. The same database was imported successfully via ssh into a remote staging site. This is the command I typed and what I see in response. Would anyone be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

```
source /Users/childhope/Desktop/childhope_org_3-3.sql<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: SET: command not found<br>
-bash: SET: command not found<br>
-bash: /*!40101: No such file or directory<br>
-bash: /*!40101: No such file or directory<br>
-bash: /*!40101: No such file or directory<br>
-bash: /*!40101: No such file or directory<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: childhope_org_3: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: ts_redirects: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: --: command not found<br>
-bash: /Users/childhope/Desktop/childhope_org_3-3.sql: line 29: syntax error near unexpected token `('<br>
-bash: /Users/childhope/Desktop/childhope_org_3-3.sql: line 29: `CREATE TABLE `ts_redirects` ('<br>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the sql file?

Comment: Or more probably, is my local terminal/ssh set up differently than the remote?